# Pushing a view controller from an CFCoverFlowView

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi Im developing an app in which I'm using a third party library called CFCoverFlowView (Can't link It but if you just Google CFCoverFlowView you will find the GitHub site).

What I want to accomplish Is to be able to push septet ViewControllers when the different images is clicked. Im using Storyboard so I would like to use the

```
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@""
```

In the library you get the following line to use when an image is clicked:

```
- (void)coverFlowView:(CFCoverFlowView *)coverFlowView didSelectPageItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;
```

And i have done this to make sure that it works with `UIAlertView`:

```
- (void)coverFlowView:(CFCoverFlowView *)coverFlowView didSelectPageItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;
{

if (index == 0)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"0" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

}

if (index == 1)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"1" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

}

if (index == 2)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"2" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

}

if (index == 3)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"3" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

}

if (index == 4)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"4" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

    }

}
```

And that workes, when i click on the separate images i get this (Since this Is my first question here I can't post images or more than 2 links because of my low reputation.)

Image 1 http://i60.tinypic.com/k1e4wz.png
Image 2 http://i59.tinypic.com/1g6lif.png

What I want to do Is when an image is clicked a `ViewController` with a `StoryboardID` gets pushed.

When i tried this the app crashes:

```
- (void)coverFlowView:(CFCoverFlowView *)coverFlowView didSelectPageItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;
{
    if (index == 0)
    {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main.storyboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *ViewController1 = (UIViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ViewController1 animated:YES];
    }
}
```

So if anyone could help me It would very appreciated and If anything Is missing or you don't understand my code comment and i will edit the text.

Comment: Try [storyboardWithName:@"Main"] instead of [storyboardWithName:@"Main.storyboard"]. Also, what is the crash report saying?

Comment: But I the name of my storyboard is Main.storyboard so i thought that would be what i write?

Comment: Here´s the error code               int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([DEMOAppDelegate class]));
    }
}

Comment: It's not error code. Please enable exception breakpoints.

Comment: Your storyboard's name is "Main", not "Main.storyboard". (Well, practically you're right, but .storyboard is its extension, not its "name").

Comment: Ahh of course your right! Thank you that was the problem!

Comment: Would you mind writing that as an answer so that others can se what the problem was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption : You're getting this error;

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main.storyboard'
```

Solution :

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that a typo or are you not pushing the instance of the ViewController you instantiated? You need to push **`ViewController1`**:

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:ViewController1 animated:YES];`

Comment: I saw that one just now and I edited that because It was a typo

Comment: Is your navigationController coming back nil perhaps? Are the methods `didSelectPageItemAtIndex` inside a UIViewController or perhaps a UITableViewCell?

Comment: Im not sure but the CFCoverFlowView is a UIView inside of a UIViewController

Comment: Are these methods fired on the UI thread? Have you tried wrapping your code inside this:
`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    });`